# Complicated Codes inside jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

in jQuery i want to write more codes inside .html() function. And i want to use php codes. And this style writing is very complicated. It is hard to be read.

Can i load a php/html script external ?

```
function() {
         $(this).children('.product_hover').show()
         .html('<div class="product_hover_buttons">'+
         '<button class="btn btn-success btn-large"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i> '+
         '<strong>Add to Cart</strong></button><br/><br/>'+
         '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i> '+
         '<strong>View</strong></button>'+'</div>');
    }
```

Comment: you can look at a template language like https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender or http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, keep a `template.php` file like this:

```
#template.php
<div class="product_hover_buttons">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-large"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>
<strong>Add to Cart</strong></button><br/><br/>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
<strong>View</strong></button>
</div>
```

Then you can use AJAX to load the template like this:

```js
$('#result').load('ajax/template.php');
```

In your case:

```js
function() {
  $(this).children('.product_hover').show().load('ajax/template.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Jquery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load content via another page and get the html rendered from there.

But it will be different from current scenario as it will involve a ajax call to load the html content you are loading internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.get()`.

```
$.get('path/to/html.html', function(data) {
    DOMjQueryElement.html(data); //whatever element you want
});
```

Here's the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).